# Little Bug with layer order on askubuntu

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I'm not sure if this is the right place to post, but i recently found a little rendering bug on this site. It's a problem of the z-index and the order of layers. Note: the red notification box was triggered after the "share link box" was already rendered.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting this - yes it is the right place to post